# Need to find table row having maximum number of table cell

Tags: xslt

Hi 
I am using XSLT 1.0. My input looks like,

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td/>
  <td/>
  <td/>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td/>
  <td/>
  <td/>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td/>
  <td/>
  <td/>
  <td/>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to know the maximum number of td in node. In this case, the maximum number of td is in 3rd tr and so my output should be 4. Need a template to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use recursion. Basically, the running-max template listed below runs for every tr child element of a table. It is first applied for the first child tr element, calculates the number of td elements, compares it to a running max, and then continues to do the same for following siblings, if there are any.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="count">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="table"/>
    </xsl:variable>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tr[1]" mode="running-max"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tr" mode="running-max">
    <xsl:param name="max" select="'0'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="size" select="count(td)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="newmax">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$size &gt; $max">
          <xsl:value-of select="$size"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$max"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="following-sibling::tr">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tr[position()=1]" mode="running-max">
          <xsl:with-param name="max" select="$newmax"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newmax"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I just want the count of maximum number of td in a variable in table template match itself.How to rewrite it.

Comment: Captured the results in a variable.

Comment: @Wilred-Springer: Recursion is not necessary, as shown in the answer by @Tim-C. His solution is also the more efficient one. @vignesh: I recommend using the non-recursive solution.

Comment: I have to agree with Dimitre's comment. Nevertheless, I will leave my answer here for future reference; in some cases you just need recursion. +1 for @vingesh though.

Comment: The only two cases you can't use the `xsl:for-each` solution are (a) you don't have a sequence of nodes (b) value function steps outside XPath expression scope. For (a) you can compose tokenization with maximum calculation. For (b) you can run a two phase transformation.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example which does not use recursion. It just uses an xsl:for-each to loop through the TR elements, ordering by the number of TD elements in each. The first one is then the maximum.

The maximum is put in a variable, called **maxCells** which, as an example, is made an attribute of the table.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="table"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <!-- Variable holding the maximum number of cells in a row -->
        <xsl:variable name="maxCells">
            <xsl:for-each select="tr">
                <xsl:sort select="count(td)" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(td)"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- Copy the table, adding the maximum cells as an attribute -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="MaxCells">
                <xsl:value-of select="$maxCells"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this stylesheet is applied to the provided table HTML above, the output is as follows:

```
<table MaxCells="4">
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td/>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to know if you are really trying to count cells or rather columns. What would you consider the correct result for the following table?

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="2"/><td/></tr>
    <tr><td/><td colspan="2"/></tr>
</table>
```

If you're just counting cells then you expect 2 - and that's what both previous answers provide. The table has actually three columns, however, so if that's what you're looking for (like when [converting XHTML tables to CALS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626873/html-to-cals-tables/)) you need to tweak @Tim C's solution a bit: replace *count(td)* with *sum(td/@colspan) + count(td[not(@colspan)])* both in the *<xsl:sort/>* element and in the *<xsl:value-of/>*.

Unfortunately, even then the calculation fails to provide correct column counts in all cases. For example, it comes up with 2 instead of 3 when given this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td rowspan="2"/><td/></tr>
    <tr><td/><td/></tr>
</table>
```

I have no idea how to solve that one. I've never seen it in live data either (knock on wood).

One more thing. My karma is not sufficient to comment on @Tim C's answer but I need to write this lest I forget: the stylesheet is wrong in that it sorts the cell counts lexically (i.e. it thinks "120"<"19"<"5") so if you have a row with 5 cells and another one with 10 you will get 5 as maximum. This is easy to fix by adding *data-type="number"* to the *<xsl:sort/>* tag.

Comment: This!  Plus with some table models you also have morerows that might add columns...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:variable name="table-temp">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*:table"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="$table-temp/table/descendant::tr">
            <cout>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(child::td)"/>
            </cout>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:table">
        <xsl:element name="table">
            <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:tbody">
        <xsl:element name="tbody">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*:thead">
        <xsl:element name="thead">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:tr">
        <xsl:element name="tr">
            <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
            <xsl:variable name="rowspan">
                <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*:tr/child::*:td/@rowspan">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding-sibling::*:tr/child::*:td/@rowspan)"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*:tr/child::*:th/@rowspan">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding-sibling::*:tr/child::*:th/@rowspan)"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="td-pos" select="preceding-sibling::tr[child::td/@rowspan]/position()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="th-pos" select="preceding-sibling::tr[child::th/@rowspan]/position()"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="1 to $td-pos[last()]">
                <xsl:element name="td"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to $th-pos[last()]">
                <xsl:element name="td"/>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:if test="child::*:td/@colspan|child::*:th/@colspan">
                <xsl:variable name="num">
                    <xsl:if test="child::*:th/@colspan">
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(child::*:th/@colspan)-1"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="child::*:td/@colspan">
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(child::*:td/@colspan)-1"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:for-each select="1 to $num">
                    <xsl:element name="td">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:td">
        <xsl:element name="td">
            <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:th">
        <xsl:element name="td">
            <xsl:attribute name="style"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```